# DropDownListFor Required validation only fires if optionLabel selected when another required field validation fires

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with 2 textboxes and 2 dropdown lists.

The dropdown lists have optionLabels on them and I want the required validation to show if these are selected.

One of the textboxes and both of the dropdown lists are 'Required'.

If I complete the required textbox and submit the form, the 'Required' validation on the dropdown lists doesn't fire, it only fires if the 'Required' textbox doesn't have a value.

MODELS

```
public class CreateCaseModel
    {
        public CaseRegModel CaseDetails { get; set; }
        public List<StartTypeListModel> CaseStartTypeList { get; set; }
        public List<ClientListModel> ClientsList { get; set; }
    }


public class CaseRegModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "PX Request Date")]
        public DateTime PxRequestDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Start Type")]
        public string StartType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "List Price")]
        public string ListPrice { get; set; }

    }

    public class ClientListModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Client Name")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
    }

    public class StartTypeListModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Start Type")]
        public string StartType { get; set; }
    }
```

VIEW - CreateCaseModel

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseDetails.StartType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @*@Html.DropDownList("StartType", null, "Select Start Type...", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CaseDetails.StartType, new SelectList(Model.CaseStartTypeList, "StartType", "StartType"), "Select Start Type...", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseDetails.StartType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseDetails.PxRequestDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CaseDetails.PxRequestDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseDetails.PxRequestDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseDetails.ClientId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @*@Html.DropDownList("ClientId", null, "Select Client...", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CaseDetails.ClientId, new SelectList(Model.ClientsList, "ClientId", "ClientName"), "Select Client...", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseDetails.ClientId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseDetails.ListPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CaseDetails.ListPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseDetails.ListPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
// GET: Case/Create
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            //start type list
            //var CategoryList = new List<string>();
            var qStartTypes = (from st in efContext.CaseStartTypes
                             orderby st.Id
                             select new StartTypeListModel
                             {
                                 Id = st.Id,
                                 StartType = st.StartType
                             }).ToList();


            //client list
            //var CategoryList = new List<string>();
            var qClients = (from c in efContext.PgsClients
                               orderby c.ClientName
                               select new ClientListModel
                               {
                                   ClientId = c.ClientId,
                                   ClientName = c.ClientName
                               }).ToList();


            return View(new CreateCaseModel
            {
                CaseDetails = new CaseRegModel(),
                CaseStartTypeList = qStartTypes,
                ClientsList = qClients
            });
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine, Are you using a jquery plugin for the dropdownlists?

Comment: @Stephen jQuery is included on the page but is not used at the moment.

Comment: I meant are you using a plugin such as Select2 or Chosen applied to the dropdownlists

Comment: @Stephen no nothing, no plugins are being used on the page at all.

Comment: Its due to something you have not shown us. Do you have any other hidden inputs for those properties? Can you show the actual html generated for one of the `<select>` tags

Comment: @Stephen I've just found out what was causing the issue. It was the 'PxRequestDate' field being type DateTime and a default date value automatically being added to this field, no idea why it was stopping the Dropdown validation from firing though! But once I changed the datatype to string for 'PxRequestDate' it worked fine, I’ll have to have a play and see if I can keep the DateTime datatype and get the validation working. Thanks for taking a look though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127183/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jboom).